# Magento: how to update just a block parameter with XML Layout Update

Tags: layout, magento, block

I have the catalog_category_default handle that has a content reference like this.

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>desc</string></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>20</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>12</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>60</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <!--action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action-->
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

I want to update it with the Layout Update from magento backend, to load a different template, so the line

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

should become

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/other-list.phtml">
```

I guess there's a better solution than remove content reference, and create a new one.
How can I update just that parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the layout update just add this:

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate"><name>catalog/product/other-list.phtml</name></action>
</reference>
```

This is possible because Magento gives all it's blocks (and models and objects) magic setters.

Comment: I don't understand. Should I call the `<block type="catalog/product_list"` directly within the layout update in the category management?

Comment: Sorry. I got ahead of myself and assumed you understood `<reference>`s.

Comment: Wow! thank you! I really missed the thing you could call reference even on single blocks, I thought it could only be used with references like "content", "left" or "right". Now everything is more clear! Thank you!