# Magento, replace block on product view on custom theme

Tags: magento, layout, themes, block, magento-1.7

We have a custom theme from a 3rd provider. The provider left some blank spaces where it is possible to add some more information. I already have settled up a custom layout, it reads the nedeed block and paints whatever I need but only on the `content` or `head` reference blocks. I can not find the needed block to be referenced to add there the needed information. I guess it should be inside the `catalog_product_view` group. How can I find it? I've found some useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5759010/1297603) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6043387/1297603) on StackOverflow, but can not get to the correct answer.

Here is what I have for now:

My layout file, *banners.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="banners/front" name="banners.front" as="banners_front"
                   template="banners/product.phtml" before="-"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

My *product.phtml* file:

```
<div>
    <h3>Hello...</h3>
    <p>This is my custom block</p>
</div>
```

Here is the `catalog_product_view` group found on the layout file *catalog.xml* from the 3rd part theme:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/slider.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lightbox/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>slideshow/jquery.slider.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <!--
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
                -->
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                    <label>Alert Urls</label>
                </block>

                <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
                    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review"><alias>product_review</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template></action>                
                    <block type="cms/block" name="product_custom_tab">
                        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>product_custom_tab</block_id></action>
                    </block>                
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                    <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
                </block>   
                <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="related_products" as="related_products" translate="label" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml">
                    <label>Related Products</label>
                </block>                

                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                    </block>
                    <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                    <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom2" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom2" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                    <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
                </block>

                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom2</block></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>5</columns></action>
                    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>5</limit></action>                
                </block>

                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>

            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_review">
            <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                    <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: All theme layout updates should be situated in `local.xml` of this theme.

Comment: @Zyava, can you please expand your comment, maybe add an answer and share some more detailed information? I'm new with magento so I need some more details to fully understand your recommendations.